# Best way to take the SQL SUM of a large data set in a distributed environement

Tags: mysql, hibernate, distributed-computing

Problem Scenario

Consider a database design for a super market. I have a two tables(A & B) to store the records of adding Items(A) to the inventory and to record sales(B). In order to get the running balance of a particular item in the shop, I have to take the sum of items from A and subtract sum of that particular items from B. Please consider this as the abstract scenario.

Assume that the number of rows in each table is very high.

My problem is what is the best practice to calculate the running balance in this case. Is it OK to write a SQL to do exactly what I mentioned above or is there any other performance wise and resources wise friendly methodology. I can't calculate the running balance real time since I am running this in a distributed environment. (using symmtericds). Hence in my case multiple stores adds records to their local databases and Symmetricds update those records in a master database.(Cloud) . How ever balance query will be always executed at the Master database.

Comment: How about a more reduced approach....consider a product, a sales, and a stock table...whenever there is a sale of a related product you just need to update the quantity column on the stock table for that product...

Comment: how is this question related to symmetricds?

Comment: @Hackerman yest that is possible, the problem is my application reads and writes only to the local database. So if I update the quantity column in one store(node A) and at the same time if it is updated at another store(node B), ultimately when symmetric ds update that in remote server, that will produce a faulty result. (I can't directly update the remote database since network connection is not reliable)

Comment: @BorisPavlović Symmtericds handles the bi directional replication in my case.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of it, but still can't see how is that related to the question you're asking